# Reading a file and saving each line into a variable

Tags: java, loops, file

For a project of mine, I'm trying to read a file of Integers and save each line into a file. Each of the files I'm reading have a different amount of lines.

The file would look like

> 17
> 72
> 61
> 11
> 63
> 95
> 100

Is there a way I can use a loop and save the value in a different variable for each line?

Comment: Not really, but you can save all lines into a collection - list, array, set, whatever is needed.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an array.

Comment: can you clarify? you have several files as an input? do each file only have one line of integers? Are you trying to copy every lines into another file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Collection to capture your values.  We can use a List so we maintain the input order.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create a mechanism for reading from the file.  A common option is a Scanner.  The Scanner is Autoclosable so we'll put it in a try-with-resources block so we don't have to close it ourselves.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
  ... do stuff ...
}
```

While the Scanner has values, read a value and add it to the List.

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

In sum...

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(yourFileName)) {
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextInt());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to take a line and copy it into another file, here you go: [Reading the file as long as there are lines](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-read-file-line-by-line) and just change `System.out.println(line);` (line 16) to [create and write to the file](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_create.asp) (and there just add an incrementing index (like `index++` executed at the end of "while") to the filename and pass "line" to the write function).

The only thing that is **important: close the BufferedReader and the FileWriter!!**

Something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileLineByLineUsingBufferedReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            int index = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                createFile(index);
                writeToFile(line, index);
                index++;
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void CreateFile (int index) {
  try {
    File myObj = new File("filename" + index + ".txt");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void WriteToFile (String content, int index) {
  try {
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("filename" + index + ".txt");
    myWriter.write(content);
    myWriter.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: please do not use images for code - copy as text

Comment: Sorry, I've been a bit in a hurry. I'll edit that